# How to overlay points and line on same plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to display the fitted curve of a GAM that I have run with the data points that went into the GAM, in one plot. I'm able to get R to plot them separately by entering the following code, but would like to display them on one plot together.

```
NewDay <- gam (INI~s(day), family = gaussian, data = INI_New_Day)

plot(NewDay)

plot(INI_New_Day3$day, INI_New_Day$INI))
```

I am a novice R user

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`plot` usually makes a brand new plot. If you want to add something to an existing plot, you can use `points()` or `lines()` (or `text()` or whatever function corresponds to what you're adding). For your example, this should work:

```
NewDay <- gam (INI~s(day), family = gaussian, data = INI_New_Day)

plot(NewDay)
points(INI_New_Day3$day, INI_New_Day$INI))
```

You can often get away with using `plot` and passing argument `new = TRUE`, but I've run in to problems when I try to rely on that so I always just call `points` or `lines`. From `?par`:

> `new` logical, defaulting to FALSE. If set to TRUE, the next
>   high-level plotting command (actually plot.new) should not clean the
>   frame before drawing as if it were on a new device. It is an error
>   (ignored with a warning) to try to use new = TRUE on a device that
>   does not currently contain a high-level plot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also plot the points directly using `plot(NewDay, residuals=T,pch=15)`